# Can aggregate() be used in R to find the highest value in a list of observations grouped by an id, along with other values from that observation?

Tags: r, dataframe

thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

I'm using a dataset with multiple observations per grouping ID (long form data). I've been using aggregate() to select the highest value per ID, since this lets me append that highest value to a wide form dataframe with only 1 instance of each ID.

This is how I do that:

```
example.df <- data.frame (id  = c(rep(1:3, each = 3)), 
sex = c("M", "", "", "F", "", "", "M", "", ""), 
value = c(1:9), 
date = c("01-01-2021", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2019", "01-01-2018", "01-01-2017", "01-01-2016", "01-01-2015", "01-01-2014", "01-01-2013"))

highest_value <- aggregate(value ~ id, data = example.df, max)

example_subset <- (select(example.df, "id", "sex"))
example_subset <- (subset(example_subset, sex!=""))

example_subset <- merge(example_subset, highest_value, by.x = "id", by.y = "id", all.x = T)
```

This creates a dataframe with ID, sex, and the highest value for that ID. However, I would also like to append the date corresponding with that highest value to the dataframe. I can't find out how to do that with aggregate, since aggregate only lets me select multiple sum_vars which then all have fun=max applied to them.

The result I would like:

```
example_subset$date <- c("01-01-2019", "01-01-2016", "01-01-2013")
example_subset
```

Is aggregate() usable for this, or am I approaching the problem using the wrong tool for the job?

Edit--it appears my example data isn't a great match. Here is a dput of the data I'm working with:

```
structure(list(id = c("20001", "20002", "20002", "20004", "20004"
), echo_lvef = c(30, 50, 50, 60, 55), echo_date = c("2019-11-21", 
"2013-06-14", "2013-06-14", "2012-02-07", "2017-09-14")), na.action = structure(c(`2` = 2L, 
`5` = 5L, `6` = 6L, `7` = 7L, `8` = 8L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, 
`14` = 14L, `15` = 15L, `16` = 16L, `17` = 17L, `18` = 18L, `20` = 20L, 
`21` = 21L, `25` = 25L, `26` = 26L, `27` = 27L, `28` = 28L, `29` = 29L, 
`30` = 30L, `31` = 31L, `36` = 36L, `40` = 40L, `42` = 42L, `43` = 43L, 
`44` = 44L, `45` = 45L, `46` = 46L, `47` = 47L, `50` = 50L, `51` = 51L, 
`52` = 52L, `53` = 53L, `54` = 54L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, 
`60` = 60L, `64` = 64L, `66` = 66L, `69` = 69L, `70` = 70L, `71` = 71L, 
`72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `76` = 76L, `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, `80` = 80L, 
`82` = 82L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, `87` = 87L, `88` = 88L, `89` = 89L, 
`90` = 90L, `91` = 91L, `94` = 94L, `95` = 95L, `100` = 100L, 
`101` = 101L, `102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, 
`110` = 110L, `116` = 116L, `117` = 117L, `122` = 122L, `123` = 123L, 
`124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, `127` = 127L, `128` = 128L, `129` = 129L, 
`130` = 130L, `131` = 131L, `134` = 134L, `135` = 135L, `136` = 136L, 
`144` = 144L, `145` = 145L, `146` = 146L, `147` = 147L, `148` = 148L, 
`149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, `151` = 151L, `152` = 152L, `155` = 155L, 
`157` = 157L, `158` = 158L, `159` = 159L, `160` = 160L, `161` = 161L, 
`162` = 162L, `163` = 163L, `164` = 164L, `168` = 168L, `169` = 169L, 
`170` = 170L, `180` = 180L, `184` = 184L, `185` = 185L, `186` = 186L, 
`187` = 187L, `188` = 188L, `189` = 189L, `190` = 190L, `191` = 191L, 
`192` = 192L, `193` = 193L, `194` = 194L, `199` = 199L, `201` = 201L, 
`204` = 204L, `212` = 212L, `216` = 216L, `217` = 217L, `224` = 224L, 
`225` = 225L, `227` = 227L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `239` = 239L, 
`243` = 243L, `244` = 244L, `245` = 245L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, 
`254` = 254L, `255` = 255L, `256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, 
`269` = 269L, `270` = 270L, `271` = 271L, `272` = 272L, `273` = 273L, 
`274` = 274L, `280` = 280L, `281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `286` = 286L, 
`287` = 287L, `290` = 290L, `291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `296` = 296L, 
`297` = 297L, `298` = 298L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, `304` = 304L, 
`306` = 306L, `307` = 307L, `308` = 308L, `319` = 319L, `320` = 320L, 
`331` = 331L, `333` = 333L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, `338` = 338L, 
`350` = 350L, `353` = 353L, `358` = 358L, `359` = 359L, `367` = 367L, 
`369` = 369L, `370` = 370L, `371` = 371L, `372` = 372L, `377` = 377L, 
`379` = 379L, `380` = 380L, `381` = 381L, `387` = 387L, `395` = 395L, 
`396` = 396L, `397` = 397L, `399` = 399L, `400` = 400L, `404` = 404L, 
`407` = 407L, `408` = 408L, `412` = 412L, `413` = 413L, `414` = 414L, 
`415` = 415L, `420` = 420L, `421` = 421L, `428` = 428L, `429` = 429L, 
`430` = 430L, `431` = 431L, `437` = 437L, `444` = 444L, `445` = 445L, 
`446` = 446L, `447` = 447L, `450` = 450L, `451` = 451L, `452` = 452L, 
`453` = 453L, `459` = 459L, `460` = 460L, `461` = 461L, `466` = 466L, 
`473` = 473L, `475` = 475L, `485` = 485L, `486` = 486L, `487` = 487L, 
`488` = 488L, `492` = 492L, `493` = 493L, `500` = 500L, `501` = 501L, 
`502` = 502L, `503` = 503L, `504` = 504L, `505` = 505L, `506` = 506L, 
`507` = 507L, `509` = 509L, `510` = 510L, `511` = 511L, `512` = 512L, 
`513` = 513L, `514` = 514L, `516` = 516L, `517` = 517L, `518` = 518L, 
`519` = 519L, `529` = 529L, `530` = 530L, `531` = 531L, `532` = 532L, 
`533` = 533L, `534` = 534L, `549` = 549L, `550` = 550L, `551` = 551L, 
`552` = 552L, `553` = 553L, `554` = 554L, `556` = 556L, `558` = 558L, 
`559` = 559L, `563` = 563L, `576` = 576L, `577` = 577L, `578` = 578L, 
`579` = 579L, `580` = 580L, `581` = 581L, `582` = 582L, `588` = 588L, 
`596` = 596L, `600` = 600L, `601` = 601L, `605` = 605L, `606` = 606L, 
`614` = 614L, `621` = 621L, `631` = 631L, `637` = 637L, `644` = 644L, 
`647` = 647L, `648` = 648L, `660` = 660L, `661` = 661L, `662` = 662L, 
`663` = 663L, `671` = 671L, `672` = 672L, `673` = 673L, `674` = 674L, 
`676` = 676L, `677` = 677L, `678` = 678L, `688` = 688L, `689` = 689L, 
`690` = 690L, `699` = 699L, `700` = 700L, `701` = 701L, `703` = 703L, 
`707` = 707L, `708` = 708L, `710` = 710L, `712` = 712L, `713` = 713L, 
`714` = 714L, `715` = 715L, `716` = 716L, `717` = 717L, `718` = 718L, 
`719` = 719L, `720` = 720L, `721` = 721L, `722` = 722L, `731` = 731L, 
`732` = 732L, `733` = 733L, `734` = 734L, `742` = 742L, `743` = 743L, 
`745` = 745L, `752` = 752L, `756` = 756L, `757` = 757L, `758` = 758L, 
`759` = 759L, `760` = 760L, `761` = 761L, `764` = 764L, `765` = 765L, 
`766` = 766L, `767` = 767L, `775` = 775L, `776` = 776L, `781` = 781L, 
`782` = 782L, `783` = 783L, `789` = 789L, `790` = 790L, `791` = 791L, 
`794` = 794L, `796` = 796L, `797` = 797L, `814` = 814L, `815` = 815L, 
`816` = 816L, `817` = 817L, `818` = 818L, `819` = 819L, `820` = 820L, 
`821` = 821L, `822` = 822L, `838` = 838L, `839` = 839L, `868` = 868L, 
`869` = 869L, `870` = 870L, `871` = 871L, `872` = 872L, `873` = 873L, 
`874` = 874L, `875` = 875L, `878` = 878L, `879` = 879L, `880` = 880L, 
`887` = 887L, `888` = 888L, `889` = 889L, `895` = 895L, `896` = 896L, 
`897` = 897L, `898` = 898L, `899` = 899L, `901` = 901L, `907` = 907L, 
`912` = 912L, `913` = 913L, `914` = 914L, `918` = 918L, `919` = 919L, 
`920` = 920L, `921` = 921L, `922` = 922L, `923` = 923L, `928` = 928L, 
`929` = 929L, `930` = 930L, `931` = 931L, `932` = 932L, `933` = 933L, 
`934` = 934L, `935` = 935L, `936` = 936L, `937` = 937L, `940` = 940L, 
`941` = 941L, `951` = 951L, `959` = 959L, `960` = 960L, `971` = 971L, 
`973` = 973L, `974` = 974L, `981` = 981L, `988` = 988L, `1005` = 1005L, 
`1013` = 1013L, `1014` = 1014L, `1015` = 1015L, `1019` = 1019L, 
`1020` = 1020L, `1021` = 1021L, `1022` = 1022L, `1023` = 1023L, 
`1024` = 1024L, `1025` = 1025L, `1026` = 1026L, `1027` = 1027L, 
`1028` = 1028L, `1034` = 1034L, `1035` = 1035L, `1036` = 1036L, 
`1037` = 1037L, `1038` = 1038L, `1039` = 1039L, `1040` = 1040L, 
`1041` = 1041L, `1043` = 1043L, `1044` = 1044L, `1045` = 1045L, 
`1046` = 1046L, `1047` = 1047L, `1064` = 1064L, `1065` = 1065L, 
`1066` = 1066L, `1067` = 1067L, `1068` = 1068L, `1075` = 1075L, 
`1083` = 1083L, `1084` = 1084L, `1085` = 1085L, `1094` = 1094L, 
`1095` = 1095L, `1105` = 1105L, `1106` = 1106L, `1107` = 1107L, 
`1117` = 1117L, `1118` = 1118L, `1119` = 1119L, `1120` = 1120L, 
`1121` = 1121L, `1123` = 1123L, `1133` = 1133L, `1134` = 1134L, 
`1155` = 1155L, `1162` = 1162L, `1163` = 1163L, `1164` = 1164L, 
`1165` = 1165L, `1166` = 1166L, `1167` = 1167L, `1168` = 1168L, 
`1172` = 1172L, `1173` = 1173L, `1174` = 1174L, `1181` = 1181L, 
`1182` = 1182L, `1188` = 1188L, `1189` = 1189L, `1190` = 1190L, 
`1195` = 1195L, `1196` = 1196L, `1197` = 1197L, `1198` = 1198L, 
`1199` = 1199L, `1209` = 1209L, `1211` = 1211L, `1212` = 1212L, 
`1213` = 1213L, `1214` = 1214L, `1215` = 1215L, `1216` = 1216L, 
`1217` = 1217L, `1218` = 1218L, `1226` = 1226L, `1240` = 1240L, 
`1241` = 1241L, `1247` = 1247L, `1248` = 1248L, `1249` = 1249L, 
`1250` = 1250L, `1251` = 1251L, `1252` = 1252L, `1261` = 1261L, 
`1268` = 1268L, `1273` = 1273L, `1274` = 1274L, `1275` = 1275L, 
`1276` = 1276L, `1277` = 1277L, `1278` = 1278L, `1279` = 1279L, 
`1280` = 1280L, `1281` = 1281L, `1282` = 1282L, `1283` = 1283L, 
`1286` = 1286L, `1287` = 1287L, `1288` = 1288L, `1289` = 1289L, 
`1290` = 1290L, `1294` = 1294L, `1295` = 1295L, `1296` = 1296L, 
`1297` = 1297L, `1298` = 1298L, `1301` = 1301L, `1302` = 1302L, 
`1310` = 1310L, `1318` = 1318L, `1324` = 1324L, `1325` = 1325L, 
`1329` = 1329L, `1330` = 1330L, `1331` = 1331L, `1332` = 1332L, 
`1333` = 1333L, `1335` = 1335L, `1338` = 1338L, `1349` = 1349L, 
`1350` = 1350L, `1353` = 1353L, `1354` = 1354L, `1355` = 1355L, 
`1356` = 1356L, `1357` = 1357L, `1360` = 1360L, `1362` = 1362L, 
`1363` = 1363L, `1368` = 1368L, `1369` = 1369L, `1376` = 1376L, 
`1377` = 1377L, `1383` = 1383L, `1387` = 1387L, `1390` = 1390L, 
`1399` = 1399L, `1400` = 1400L, `1401` = 1401L, `1402` = 1402L, 
`1405` = 1405L, `1406` = 1406L, `1407` = 1407L, `1408` = 1408L, 
`1410` = 1410L, `1417` = 1417L, `1422` = 1422L, `1423` = 1423L, 
`1434` = 1434L, `1435` = 1435L, `1436` = 1436L, `1437` = 1437L, 
`1438` = 1438L, `1439` = 1439L, `1440` = 1440L, `1441` = 1441L, 
`1442` = 1442L, `1443` = 1443L, `1444` = 1444L, `1445` = 1445L, 
`1448` = 1448L, `1449` = 1449L, `1452` = 1452L, `1453` = 1453L, 
`1454` = 1454L, `1455` = 1455L, `1456` = 1456L, `1459` = 1459L, 
`1460` = 1460L, `1461` = 1461L, `1462` = 1462L, `1467` = 1467L, 
`1470` = 1470L, `1471` = 1471L, `1472` = 1472L, `1473` = 1473L, 
`1484` = 1484L, `1489` = 1489L, `1499` = 1499L, `1500` = 1500L, 
`1501` = 1501L, `1502` = 1502L, `1503` = 1503L, `1504` = 1504L, 
`1505` = 1505L, `1506` = 1506L, `1509` = 1509L, `1510` = 1510L, 
`1511` = 1511L, `1512` = 1512L, `1513` = 1513L, `1516` = 1516L, 
`1517` = 1517L, `1518` = 1518L, `1525` = 1525L, `1527` = 1527L, 
`1528` = 1528L, `1529` = 1529L, `1532` = 1532L, `1533` = 1533L, 
`1534` = 1534L, `1536` = 1536L, `1537` = 1537L, `1540` = 1540L, 
`1541` = 1541L, `1546` = 1546L, `1551` = 1551L, `1553` = 1553L, 
`1554` = 1554L, `1557` = 1557L, `1560` = 1560L, `1561` = 1561L, 
`1568` = 1568L, `1569` = 1569L, `1571` = 1571L, `1572` = 1572L, 
`1581` = 1581L, `1582` = 1582L, `1583` = 1583L, `1591` = 1591L, 
`1592` = 1592L, `1593` = 1593L, `1594` = 1594L, `1595` = 1595L, 
`1596` = 1596L, `1597` = 1597L, `1598` = 1598L, `1599` = 1599L, 
`1601` = 1601L, `1604` = 1604L, `1609` = 1609L, `1612` = 1612L, 
`1614` = 1614L, `1615` = 1615L, `1616` = 1616L, `1617` = 1617L, 
`1619` = 1619L, `1620` = 1620L, `1622` = 1622L, `1623` = 1623L, 
`1624` = 1624L, `1626` = 1626L, `1630` = 1630L, `1631` = 1631L, 
`1632` = 1632L, `1636` = 1636L, `1637` = 1637L, `1641` = 1641L, 
`1648` = 1648L, `1649` = 1649L, `1651` = 1651L, `1653` = 1653L, 
`1654` = 1654L, `1655` = 1655L, `1661` = 1661L, `1662` = 1662L, 
`1663` = 1663L, `1664` = 1664L, `1666` = 1666L, `1667` = 1667L, 
`1668` = 1668L, `1670` = 1670L, `1672` = 1672L, `1674` = 1674L, 
`1675` = 1675L, `1676` = 1676L, `1679` = 1679L, `1680` = 1680L, 
`1681` = 1681L, `1692` = 1692L, `1693` = 1693L, `1700` = 1700L, 
`1701` = 1701L, `1706` = 1706L, `1707` = 1707L, `1708` = 1708L, 
`1709` = 1709L, `1715` = 1715L, `1719` = 1719L, `1722` = 1722L, 
`1724` = 1724L, `1725` = 1725L, `1734` = 1734L, `1735` = 1735L, 
`1737` = 1737L, `1739` = 1739L, `1740` = 1740L, `1745` = 1745L, 
`1747` = 1747L, `1754` = 1754L, `1755` = 1755L, `1757` = 1757L, 
`1760` = 1760L, `1761` = 1761L, `1762` = 1762L, `1764` = 1764L, 
`1765` = 1765L, `1766` = 1766L, `1769` = 1769L, `1770` = 1770L, 
`1771` = 1771L, `1772` = 1772L, `1778` = 1778L, `1779` = 1779L, 
`1780` = 1780L, `1783` = 1783L, `1784` = 1784L, `1788` = 1788L, 
`1790` = 1790L, `1791` = 1791L, `1798` = 1798L, `1799` = 1799L, 
`1800` = 1800L, `1801` = 1801L, `1802` = 1802L, `1803` = 1803L, 
`1804` = 1804L, `1805` = 1805L, `1807` = 1807L, `1808` = 1808L, 
`1811` = 1811L, `1814` = 1814L, `1815` = 1815L, `1820` = 1820L, 
`1823` = 1823L, `1826` = 1826L, `1827` = 1827L, `1830` = 1830L, 
`1832` = 1832L, `1840` = 1840L, `1841` = 1841L, `1844` = 1844L, 
`1850` = 1850L, `1851` = 1851L, `1861` = 1861L, `1862` = 1862L, 
`1863` = 1863L, `1864` = 1864L, `1870` = 1870L, `1871` = 1871L, 
`1877` = 1877L, `1878` = 1878L, `1879` = 1879L, `1886` = 1886L, 
`1889` = 1889L, `1891` = 1891L, `1892` = 1892L, `1893` = 1893L, 
`1894` = 1894L, `1895` = 1895L, `1896` = 1896L, `1897` = 1897L, 
`1898` = 1898L, `1899` = 1899L, `1900` = 1900L, `1901` = 1901L, 
`1902` = 1902L, `1903` = 1903L, `1904` = 1904L, `1905` = 1905L, 
`1906` = 1906L, `1907` = 1907L, `1908` = 1908L, `1909` = 1909L, 
`1910` = 1910L, `1911` = 1911L, `1912` = 1912L, `1913` = 1913L, 
`1914` = 1914L, `1915` = 1915L, `1916` = 1916L, `1917` = 1917L, 
`1918` = 1918L, `1919` = 1919L, `1920` = 1920L, `1921` = 1921L, 
`1922` = 1922L, `1923` = 1923L, `1924` = 1924L, `1925` = 1925L, 
`1926` = 1926L, `1927` = 1927L, `1928` = 1928L, `1929` = 1929L, 
`1930` = 1930L, `1931` = 1931L, `1932` = 1932L, `1933` = 1933L, 
`1934` = 1934L, `1935` = 1935L, `1936` = 1936L, `1937` = 1937L, 
`1938` = 1938L, `1939` = 1939L, `1940` = 1940L, `1941` = 1941L, 
`1942` = 1942L, `1943` = 1943L, `1944` = 1944L, `1945` = 1945L, 
`1946` = 1946L, `1947` = 1947L, `1948` = 1948L, `1949` = 1949L, 
`1950` = 1950L, `1951` = 1951L, `1953` = 1953L, `1956` = 1956L, 
`1957` = 1957L, `1958` = 1958L, `1959` = 1959L, `1960` = 1960L, 
`1961` = 1961L, `1962` = 1962L, `1963` = 1963L, `1964` = 1964L, 
`1965` = 1965L), class = "omit"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 
12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: is this that you want? `highest_value <- aggregate(. ~ id, data = example.df, max)`

Comment: Hi, not quite--I tried that, but that code returns the highest number of value but just the first date in the list, so not the date corresponding to that highest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr` you may do this

```r
example.df <- data.frame (id  = c(rep(1:3, each = 3)), 
                          sex = c("M", "", "", "F", "", "", "M", "", ""), 
                          value = c(1:9), 
                          date = c("01-01-2021", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2019", "01-01-2018", "01-01-2017", "01-01-2016", "01-01-2015", "01-01-2014", "01-01-2013"))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)


example.df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(date = date[value == max(value)],
            value = max(value), 
            sex  = first(sex))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id date       value sex  
#>   <int> <chr>      <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 01-01-2019     3 M    
#> 2     2 01-01-2016     6 F    
#> 3     3 01-01-2013     9 M
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this works! I had to remove sex from the equation, since otherwise it didn't work with my specific data. But that is no problem. As an added benefit, this shows both values/dates if 2 observations on 2 different dates resulted in the same value, and that value is the max value for this person.

Comment: @rdbr, actually changing the sequence, should do the work here.  See edit.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you, dplyr is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` after you have filled up the `NA` in column *sex*:

```
example.df$sex <- with(example.df, ave(sex, id, FUN=function(x) x[1]))
merge(example.df, highest_value)
#  id value sex       date
#1  1     3   M 01-01-2019
#2  2     6   F 01-01-2016
#3  3     9   M 01-01-2013
```

or you can use `split` instead of `aggregate`:

```
example.df[sapply(split(seq_len(nrow(example.df)), example.df$id), 
 function(i) i[example.df$value[i] == max(example.df$value[i])]),]
#  id sex value       date
#3  1   M     3 01-01-2019
#6  2   F     6 01-01-2016
#9  3   M     9 01-01-2013
```

Or in case you want only one match:

```
example.df[sapply(split(seq_len(nrow(example.df)), example.df$id), 
  function(i) i[which.max(example.df$value[i])]),]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works on my example dataset. However, when I wanted to apply it to my original dataset, I get the error "Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'". I think I minimized my example data a bit too much! I tried unlist() but that got me another error. I have appended a dput() of my own data to the original post. Thank you for your response though!

Comment: Your `dput` dataset does not have a column named *sex*, what might cause the error.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just now realized that. In my endeavor to simplify the data as much as possible, I accidentally left out some key things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with `split()` and `purrr::map()`:

```
library(dplyr)

split(example.df, ~ id) %>%
  purrr::map(~ .x %>%
          mutate(sex = max(sex)) %>%
          arrange(desc(value)) %>%
          slice_head()) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Returns:

```
  id sex value       date
1  1   M     3 01-01-2019
2  2   F     6 01-01-2016
3  3   M     9 01-01-2013
```

Data used:

```
example.df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), sex = c("M", "", "", "F", "", "", "M", "", ""), value = 1:9, date = c("01-01-2021", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2019", "01-01-2018", "01-01-2017", "01-01-2016", "01-01-2015", "01-01-2014", "01-01-2013")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. Using your example data returns an error--"Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors". Unfamiliar with purrr, so I couldn't fix this error just yet. I will work on it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the most elegant solution, but with your example it works fine:

```
highest_value <- aggregate(. ~ id, data = example.df, max)
highest_value$date <- example.df[highest_value$value,"date"]

     id sex value       date
1  1   M     3 01-01-2019
2  2   F     6 01-01-2016
3  3   M     9 01-01-2013
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. Definitely the easiest to follow solution, and it helped me understand a few commands. However, the example data I provided was not as great a match as I thought, so it doesn't work on my real dataset (but that is my fault).

Answer (score 0):

We may also use `slice_max` as an alternative to @AnilGoyal solution

```
library(dplyr)
example.df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(firstsex = first(sex)) %>%
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = value) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(sex = firstsex, firstsex = NULL)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id sex   value date      
  <int> <chr> <int> <chr>     
1     1 M         3 01-01-2019
2     2 F         6 01-01-2016
3     3 M         9 01-01-2013
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about slice_max. This works as well on the example and real code.